# I haven't paid APC but they published my paper

Tags: publications

My paper got accepted for publication in an ISI/Scopus index journal, and they charge the APC. We requested to extend the deadline for APC paying because we are looking for money. In the meantime, the journal's production team also asked us to do some tasks to publish our paper. Today, my paper got published by that journal, although we haven't paid the APC. My questions:

1. What should I do right now? Should I tell them I haven't paid the APC yet or keep silent?
2. Do they remove our paper if they realize that we haven't paid the APC? If that happens, does it negatively affect my profile?

Comment: Is the APC for publication itself, or for open access?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth It is a Gold Open Access journal so I think it's for publication itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's been this way for many years, before the advent of open access. From personal experience paying overlength charges, voluntary page charges, and color fees from the early 2000's is that publishers will often assume you will pay and send an invoice to be paid later.

I think this is due to the bureaucracy at institutions. It can often take 2-3 months for large sums of money to work their way through the system, and such unexpected delays will wreak havoc with publishing processes, especially if there's topical or special issues.

Answer (score 1):

You've assumed they made a mistake publishing your paper. That's not necessarily the case. It's possible they published anyway because they trust you will pay the APC. Why would they trust you will pay the APC? The most obvious reason is because you published previous papers with them and always paid the APC. Other reasons could be because you or your co-author are a Big Name (or member of their editorial board, etc.) and they are accommodating you.

So: don't worry about it, keep looking for the money, and pay them when you get it.

Answer (score 0):

> *We requested to extend the deadline for APC paying because we are looking for money ...
> What should I do right now? Should I tell them I haven't paid the APC yet or keep silent?*

Keep calm, continue looking for the money, and frantically make payment.

While at it, you can, *though I'll think not compulsory*, inform the managing editor (or handling editor) about the '*slipped through*' publication and your commitment to making APC payment nonetheless. Doing so would *fulfill* moral reasonableness.
PS: there might be *unseen" nuances/underlying factors leading to the publication or it might just be an inadvertent error.